# activity diagram - UML - action with no outgoing flow

Tags: architecture, uml

I am working for the first time with activity diagrams and UML.

I started with a draft of what I need to do.

One important question. Can I also draw actions which are not contributing to the flow?

You can see what I mean in the example I am attaching. The organizer needs just to read the abstract or feedback, but it doesn't influence anything about the flow.

Is that correct? Or should I just remove it?

thanks[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your diagram is almost correct. And the "actions which are not contributing to the flow" are well contributing. They are just, as you pointed out, in parallel. And that's correctly expressed by using the forks.

What I would not do is to link the objects into the control flow. I'd rather create an object flow (which looks just the same as a control flow, though) and put the object aside. This is more a personal taste, but I think that object flows should not continue a control flow and vice versa. The object is created and put aside. The control flow goes on and somewhere later the object is read again. This is what I mean it should look like:

[image]

P.S. No outgoing flows actually means that the control flow stops. Since you forked them off, the fork just dies out when the action is done. That's perfectly okay.